# Netbeans/Java how do I connect to remote database

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

I'm trying to create a java application that connects to ma remote host, retrieves some data and adds some data into the database. The problem is that I can't connect to the database on my remote host from within my application.

The application was created in Java using netbeans.

```
connection informations:
host adress  : subadr.myadress.com
database name: mydatabase_name
user name    : mydatabase_name
user password: name123
```

What I've tried this:
In netbeans, Services > Right click on Databases > New Connection. Then I used a connector which is:**mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar** Then I have entered informations that needs to. When I click on **Test Connection**  I'm getting this error all the time:

> cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://subadr.myadress.com/mydatabase_name using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Communications link failure  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)

I don't know if I have to configure something else in my host. I've contected to a database which is on my own PC(Only difference was insteed subadr.myadress.com I used localhost) problem is I can't reach the one on my host. Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: It's perhaps worth checking through the answers to this similar [Serverfault question][1].


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/89955/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-through-jdbc-connector-through-tomcat-or-externally

Comment: If what you call your host is a shared database server hosted by your ISP, there is a good chance that access to the database from the outside is simply forbidden.